# Unstable keyboard of EditText inside ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I have ListView of EditTexts, when I tap inside one of the editText that input type is number, number keyboard appear then full keyboard then number keyboard again in very short time, can I know why this happen ?

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/vitalValue"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/vitalSign"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
```

Comment: Did all of your EditText have `inputType="number"` ?

Comment: Yes, each editText inside a custom list view item and the listView contains these custom list view items